# Issue with <Text> truncation when there is a new line character in the string react-native ios

Tags: react-native

I have an issue. Please find the text display code I use inside a view

```
<Text numberOfLines={5} ellipsizeMode={"tail"}>
  {getDisplaySrting()}
</Text>
```

This piece of code is working fine in iOS and Android in the case of normal strings which span for more than 5 lines. The fifth line will end with the expected 3 dots in the view.

eg: **This is the fifth li...**

However I face an issue when there is a line break in the string, and if it is lying in the fifth line.

For eg: In the fifth line if the string was
**This is the fifth\n line**

Then in Android the fifth line will be displayed as
**This is the fifth...**

However in iOS this is shown as:
**This is the fifth**
No ellipses are shown at the end.

So it gives a feel that the strig ends at **fifth** in the case of ios.

I assume this is a limitation in iOS.
Has anyone faced this issue? Also any workarounds or recommendations here?

Comment: I can reproduce this issue. Logging what the component is rendering on layout using `onTextLayout={({ nativeEvent: { lines } }) => console.log(lines)}` shows that the last line is not rendering at all. This might be a bug and you could open an issue on Github.